# Differences between Metro and Windows Forms development

Tags: winforms, api, winapi, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Maybe is a senseless question (it is?):
it is possible to convert a Metro app in Windows Forms? What are pros and cons that should I consider?

And also: what are the differences between the two ways, in term of technologies/languages used for developing? Developing for Metro instead of Windows Forms is better only because I can run my software in a bigger number of dispositives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the answer below is from 2013. Since Windows Store was renamed Microsoft Store and Windows Runtime (WinRT) is now branded as Universal Windows Platform (UWP) - Windows Store Apps are now also more commonly known as UWP Apps (UWAs) or just Windows Apps.

---

Metro is a design language. What was formerly known as Metro Style Apps is now called Windows Store Apps.

1. The Windows Store Apps are written using Windows Runtime or WinRT for short, while Windows Forms is based on WinAPI. WinRT is more modern and has lots of improvements especially in the asynchronous APIs that make it work better for the new and upcoming solutions - especially mobile, tablet etc. Also in how languages can be mixed together and more.
2. WinRT apps can be written using a variety of languages and APIs - C#/VB.NET/C++ with WinRT-XAML, C++ with DirectX or HTML+JS+CSS with WinJS and also some combinations of these.
3. Windows Store Apps give you an easy way to make money on the apps you write.
4. Windows Store Apps out of the box support the Metro design language (akhem, Microsoft design language), while Windows Forms apps look dated unless you highly customize the controls or use third party components.
5. Windows Forms apps are written in .NET languages while Windows Store Apps can be written in C++ or JavaScript.
6. If you come from Windows Forms+C#/VB world your natural next step would be to learn how to use WinRT-XAML+C#/VB unless you would like to pick up a different language. WinRT-XAML derives from WPF and Silverlight which were created as successors to Windows Forms.

Comment: what is the corresponding of XAML in windows form?

Comment: It's the .designer.cs file auto-generated by the forms designer. XAML is XML-based declarative language used here to describe the UI. One of its premises was to enable designing the UI with external tools, making it easier for developers and designers to work together. The external designer tools usually mean Expression Blend or (less frequently) Expression Design. It also gave rise to the role of design integrators in the Microsoft developers community.

Answer (score 2):

Developing Windows.Forms applications and Windows Store Apps is like developing in two different worlds. I would not use Windows.Forms for desktop apps by the way. Use WPF. Its more modern and the UI design language (XAML) is the same as in Windows Store Apps. Although you can exchange most of the UI code between WPF and Windows Store Apps you still work with different libraries (full .NET in WPF and Windows Runtime in Windows Store Apps).

Windows Store Apps are cool and modern. They run on PCs, on tablets and phones. WPF applications only run on PCs. But Windows Store Apps are fairly limited in what they can do. Many people think that for business applications WPF is much better suited.

Hence it depends on what you want to develop. If you want to build a consumer app possibly Windows Store Apps would be better suited. If you build a business application WPF would possibly the better tool. Sad thing for newbies is though that they have to learn two very different libraries.